# Refactoring and simplify this infrastructure building code

Tags: design, architecture, refactoring, aws

I have a piece of code (a Facade) that creates every single infrastructure component on aws.

```
private void synthesizeStack() {
    Deployer<Vpc> vpcDeployer = new VpcDeployer(this);
    Deployer<Bucket> s3Deployer = new S3Deployer(this);

    Vpc vpc = vpcDeployer.deploy();
    Bucket bucket = s3Deployer.deploy();

    Deployer<SecurityGroup> bastionSecurityGroupDeployer = new BastionSecurityGroupDeployer(this, vpc);
    SecurityGroup bastionSecurityGroup = bastionSecurityGroupDeployer.deploy();
    Deployer<Instance> bastionDeployer = new BastionDeployer(this, vpc, bastionSecurityGroup);

    Deployer<SecurityGroup> rdsSecurityGroupDeployer = new RdsSecurityGroupDeployer(this, vpc, bastionSecurityGroup);
    SecurityGroup rdsSecurityGroup = rdsSecurityGroupDeployer.deploy();
    Deployer<DatabaseCluster> rdsDeployer = new RdsDeployer(this, vpc, rdsSecurityGroup);

    Deployer<List<Lambda>> lambdaDeployer = new LambdaDeployer(this, bucket);

    rdsDeployer.deploy();
    bastionDeployer.deploy();
    lambdaDeployer.deploy();
}
```

I tried to give to all deployer a common interface but each deployer has different parameters and return type so I created a generic interface.

How can I simplify this piece of code? Is there a better way?

Comment: it looks like they already have a single interface with deploy() and the parameters are passed in the constructor?

Comment: Yes, the Deployer interface contains the only T deploy() method, and all the dependencies are passed in the constructor. But I don't really need the return object on every deployer so I think this isn't a good design.

Answer (score 2):

Really you are just rearranging code to your personal tastes. You can have various arrangements such as:

- Object.Deploy()
- Deployer.Deploy(object)
- Deployer(object).Deploy()

Personally, I don't like the `Deployer(object).Deploy()` because it leaves behind a useless Deployer object.

`Object.Deploy()` is nice for things where the Object hangs around and has multiple things done to it, but in your case I imagine its more like a data object and you don't really want to put the deploying code in it as its not part of its responsibility

`Deployer.Deploy(object)` would be my favourite. You presumably are deploying several things to a single AWS account, so you can keep the Deployer around and pass it objects.

Now you have the problem that you will potentially need multiple methods on the deployer.

I don't think this is necessarily bad. However you can alleviate it it somewhat with a generic method

```
public class S3 
{ 
    public string DeploymentInstructions { get; set; }
    public string DeployedObject { get; set; }
}
public interface IDeployer
{
    T Deploy<T>(T data);
}
public class S3Deployer : IDeployer
{
    public T Deploy<T>(T data)
    {
        if(data is S3)
        {
            //deploy
            Console.WriteLine($"deploying s3 {(data as S3).DeploymentInstructions}");
            (data as S3).DeployedObject = "result of deployment";
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("type not supported");
        }
    }
}

public class GeneralDeployer : IDeployer
{
    private Dictionary<Type, IDeployer> concreteDeployers;

    public GeneralDeployer()
    {
        concreteDeployers = new Dictionary<Type, IDeployer>();
        concreteDeployers.Add(typeof(S3), new S3Deployer());
    }
    public T Deploy<T>(T data)
    {
        if(concreteDeployers.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return concreteDeployers[typeof(T)].Deploy(data);
        }
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I haven't understood your answer. How can I create a Dictionary or a Map of <DeployerType, ConcreteDeployer>? I can create an enum of DeployerType and this would be ok, but how can I put different concrete deployer in the dictionary? They don't have the same concrete type.

Comment: yeah, you could have them all implement Deploy(object o) or you could just have each one as a separate field

Comment: actually you can use the generic method all the way down

Comment: I think I have understood your solution, however in my case: 1) Some concrete deployers must return the deployed object (e.g. S3Deployer must return the deployed S3 bucket because the LambdaDeployer needs the bucket to attach a trigger or e.g. the VpcDeployer must return the deployed Vpc because the DatabaseDeployer needs the Vpc); 2) Every concrete deployer have different dependencies on the constructor: if I use a generic deployer to deploy all them then I need to pass all dependencies to the generic deployer. Am I missing something of your solution?

Comment: you can solve the return type easily enough with the same pattern and yes pass in the dependencies (but not the object you are deploying) to the Deployer

Comment: in this case the dependencies are the concrete deployers

Comment: Ok it's clearer now. But how would you deal with the type erasure of parameter data in the method public T Deploy<T>(T data) in the GeneralDeployer? In Java I can't have the runtime type of a generic T type.

Comment: not sure, #worksincsharp #useagoodlanguage ?

Comment: the generic here obvs just gets compiled out into a method per type thats passed to it. I would be equally happy hardcoding the GeneralDeployer with multiple methods. You have the fixed list of AWS things so there isnt a huge need to get super generic

Comment: keeping the underlying generic though allows you to code up multiple deployers which presumably share a large amount of code and plop em in as you write them